# How to write these line of code in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.6

I am very new in cakephp and i have to upgrade a cake project from version 1.1 to 3.6. I do not know how to convert these lines of code to cakephp 3.6:

```
    App::import('Model', 'SystemMenu');
    $system_menu =& new SystemMenu();
```

SystemMenu is an model which was define in Model folder.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: bin/cake bake model SystemMenus , bin/cake bake cell SystemMenus, load model in display method and make query, implement results in display.ctp template. use template....

Answer (score 1):

If youre within a controller, you can do

```
$this->loadModel('SystemMenus');
```

and access the model like so

```
$this->SystemMenus->find()->...
```

If not, you can use TableRegistry

```
$systemMenus = TableRegistry::get('SystemMenus')
```

And access is simple:

```
$systemMenus->find()->...
```

See https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html for more information

Notice that i have changed the table name to be plural, as the CakePHP 3.x conventions specifies https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html

Comment: Your solution helps save much time for me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TableRegistry` class.

```
$system_menu = \Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get('SystemMenu');

//new entity
$entity = $system_menu->newEntity();

//get entity by id 
$entity = $system_menu->get(2);

//Save entity
$system_menu->save($e);

// finder 
$menu = $system_menu->find()->toArray();
```